# TextView in android reverts to previous value when the back button is pressed while the keyboard is open

Tags: java, android, listview, back-button

I have an activity in my Android project that revolves around group messaging.  The messages are contained in a ListView, and each row has a like button.  When the like button is pressed, a label with the total number of likes increases by one (and subtracts a like if it is unclicked).  However, when you like a message while the keyboard is open, and then press the back button, the keyboard will close and the most recently liked/unliked message will revert back to it's previous like count.  Is there anything I can add to the TextView to prevent it from doing this?  Or maybe something I can do to `onBackButtonPressed()` ?  Thanks for your help.

This is the code where I change the likeCount text:

```
    class MessageInfo {
    public String messageID;
    public String messageContent;
    public String messageLikes;
    public String senderID;
}

class ViewHolder {

    public TextView messageContent = null;
    public TextView messageLikeCount = null;
    public Button likeButton = null;
    public String messageLikes = null;
    public String messageID = null;


    public String messageSendTime;
    public String senderID;

    final CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            keys.getIdPool(), // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
    );

    public AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDb = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
            .createClient(
                    AmazonDynamoDBClient.class,
                    credentialsProvider,
                    new ClientConfiguration()
            );

    ViewHolder(View row) {
        messageContent = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        messageLikeCount = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.likeCountText);
        likeButton = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);

        likeButton.setTypeface(fontAwesome);
    }

    void populateFrom(final MessageInfo message) {

        Log.e("MESSAGE2", "The message is " + message.messageContent);

        messageContent.setText(message.messageContent);
        messageID = message.messageID;
        messageLikes = message.messageLikes;

        int likeCount = 0;

        if (messageLikes == null) {
            messageLikes = "";
        }

        Log.e("MessageLikes", "Mesage likes is " + messageLikes);

        if (messageLikes.contains(userInfo.getProfId())) {
            likeButton.setText(getString(R.string.icon_heart_closed));
            likeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHeart));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < messageLikes.length(); i++) {

            if (messageLikes.charAt(i) == ',') {

                likeCount += 1;

            }

        } // end for loop to get number of likes


        messageLikeCount.setText(String.valueOf(likeCount));




        likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("Clicked", "Like button clicked");

                likeButton.setText(getString(R.string.icon_heart_closed));
                likeButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorHeart));

                int newLikeCount = Integer.parseInt(messageLikeCount.getText().toString()) + 1;
                messageLikeCount.setText(String.valueOf(newLikeCount));

            }
        });

    }

}

class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MessageInfo> {
    MessageAdapter() {
        super(SingleGroupActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messageArr);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder messageViewHolder;

        Log.e("MESSAGE", "The message is " + messageArr.get(position).messageContent);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_row_layout, null);

            messageViewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(messageViewHolder);
        } else {

            messageViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (messageArr.size() > 0) {
            MessageInfo tempMessage = messageArr.get(position);
            messageViewHolder.populateFrom(tempMessage);
        }


        return (convertView);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you tried to close keyboard when tapping on the like button?

Comment: I don't think it's recommended to close the keyboard programmatically. User should close the keyboard when they are done typing.

Comment: @hermt2 can you post the code where you are updating the like count?

Comment: The keyboard automatically closes when I press the back button for the first time.  And yes I will add that code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide keyboard when user tap on like button with this code:

```
public static void hideKeypad(Activity context) {
    View view = context.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
      InputMethodManager imm =
      (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: I added this to the code, and now as soon as I like a message, the keyboard closes and the likeCount text still reverts to the previous value.  So it looks like it's the keyboard closing that is throwing off the text field value.